# Imagemagick and wordpress script generating two images

Tags: imagemagick, wordpress

I am using imagemagick to process an image from a URL stored in a wordpress custom field.  The script actually does what it is meant to apart from one thing, it processed an extra image every time.  The code is below....

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<?php
    $url1 = '/home/sites/public_html/mysite/wp-content/themes/mytheme/images/';
    $imagefile = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'image_url', $single = true);
    $file = basename($imagefile);
    $location = '/usr/bin/convert';
    $command = '-resize 560x';
    $convert = $location . ' ' .$command . ' ' . $imagefile . ' ' . $url1 . $file;
    exec ($convert);    
?>

<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

The extra image it creates is the same one everytime and is the first post in my post list, im not sure if it being the first post is related or not.

I am also unsure if it is imagemagick that is causing the issues or wordpress, the imagemagick commands I am using are really simple so I am leaning towards wordpress.

Can anyone suggest anything?

**UPDATE**

I have been playing around and have found that this issue only seems to happen with a couple of posts.  I have checked in the SQL database and compared them with one that isn't affected and can't see anything obvious.

**UPDATE 2**
To make things even stranger I have duplicated this setup on a local dev server, I am UNABLE to replicate it.  Everything works fine!  If I do the same thing on my shared host then the problem comes back.  This is making me think there must be some config somewhere causing it.

On the shared host if I do the following code then it works correctly....

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<?php
    $url1 = '/home/sites/public_html/mysite/wp-content/themes/mytheme/images/';
    $imagefile = 'http://www.mydomain.com/images/myimage.jpg';
    $file = basename($imagefile);
    $location = '/usr/bin/convert';
    $command = '-resize 560x';
    $convert = $location . ' ' .$command . ' ' . $imagefile . ' ' . $url1 . $file;
    exec ($convert);   
?>

<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

But if I revert back to my original code where the image URL is being generated by the wordpress get_post_meta command then I get the extra image.

**UPDATE 3**
Using the wordpress plugin BlackBox, I have been able to find a bit more information out about what is happening, the logs give me this info..

```
0.2501 [ms] SELECT * FROM wp_users WHERE user_login = 'admin';
0.1330 [ms] SELECT user_id, meta_key, meta_value FROM wp_usermeta WHERE user_id IN (1);
0.0739 [ms] SELECT option_value FROM wp_options WHERE option_name = 'theme_switched' LIMIT 1;
0.1280 [ms] SELECT ID, post_name, post_parent FROM wp_posts WHERE post_name IN ('uncategorized','my-test-post-75') AND (post_type = 'page' OR post_type = 'attachment');
0.1481 [ms] SELECT wp_posts.* FROM wp_posts  WHERE 1=1  AND wp_posts.post_name = 'my-test-post-75' AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post'  ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC ;
0.1359 [ms] SELECT t.*, tt.*, tr.object_id FROM wp_terms AS t INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy AS tt ON tt.term_id = t.term_id INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships AS tr ON tr.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id WHERE tt.taxonomy IN ('category', 'post_tag', 'post_format') AND tr.object_id IN (215) ORDER BY t.name ASC;
0.1402 [ms] SELECT post_id, meta_key, meta_value FROM wp_postmeta WHERE post_id IN (215);
0.1140 [ms] SELECT t.*, tt.* FROM wp_terms AS t INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy AS tt ON t.term_id = tt.term_id WHERE tt.taxonomy IN ('category') AND t.slug = 'uncategorized' ORDER BY t.name ASC ;
0.1018 [ms] SELECT tr.term_taxonomy_id FROM wp_term_relationships AS tr INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy AS tt ON tr.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id WHERE tr.object_id IN (215) AND tt.taxonomy IN ('category') ORDER BY tr.term_taxonomy_id ASC;
0.1259 [ms] SELECT p.* FROM wp_posts AS p  WHERE p.post_date < '2011-06-07 20:40:34' AND p.post_type = 'post' AND p.post_status = 'publish'  ORDER BY p.post_date DESC LIMIT 1;
0.0758 [ms] SELECT t.*, tt.* FROM wp_terms AS t INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy AS tt ON tt.term_id = t.term_id INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships AS tr ON tr.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id WHERE tt.taxonomy IN ('category') AND tr.object_id IN (204) ORDER BY t.name ASC;
0.0651 [ms] SELECT p.* FROM wp_posts AS p  WHERE p.post_date > '2011-06-07 20:40:34' AND p.post_type = 'post' AND p.post_status = 'publish'  ORDER BY p.post_date ASC LIMIT 1;
0.0849 [ms] SELECT t.*, tt.* FROM wp_terms AS t INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy AS tt ON tt.term_id = t.term_id INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships AS tr ON tr.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id WHERE tt.taxonomy IN ('category') AND tr.object_id IN (251) ORDER BY t.name ASC;
```

Does this new info shed any light on what could be happening?

Comment: ... you're running imagemagick on every pageview? At least check if the file already exists!

Comment: Checking if the file exists is stage two, not much point doing that until the code is working correctly.

Comment: Could you add an `echo $convert` before the `exec` so we can see that the command you are `exec`-ing matches what we expect? Also, so we can see how many times the command is being called and with which files?

Comment: I have added the line in and can see the following '/usr/bin/convert -fuzz 1% -trim -resize 560x image1.jpg /home/sites/public_html/mysite/wp-content/themes/mytheme/images/image1.jpg'  -  It only runs the once as far as I can see but in the images folder I still end up with image1.jpg and image2.jpg

Comment: Not sure if its an issue, but shouldn't you be calling get_post_meta like so, $imagefile = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'image_url', true);

Comment: Stupid question, but what is the result you're getting from get_post_meta? Also, stupid question, but are you deleting the images between tests?

Comment: Which theme file are you putting this in?  Seems loop-related and it may depend which type of page you're accessing how many times you're going through the loop and getting the thumbnails created.

Comment: What do you get in return if you run `SELECT post_id, meta_key, meta_value FROM wp_postmeta WHERE post_id IN (215)` in MySQL?

Answer (score 1):

I have little experience with imagemagick, but I've experienced a similar situation using the WordPress core functionality for resizing, it'll affect  new images added, but not the older images, added prior to the new image size code.

There is a great little utility plugin called "regenerate thumbnails", which sorted this out for me,

you can find it in the wordpress codex here.

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/

Answer (score 0):

All of the functionality you are looking for is currently available in the wordpress core - no need to add your own imagemagick functions:

in functions.php of your theme:

```
if ( function_exists( 'add_image_size' ) ) { 
    add_image_size( 'custom-size', 560, 560, false ); 
    // or set last option to true for cropping
}
```

(more info: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_image_size)

in your page.php or other theme file:

```
<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($page->ID, 'custom-size'); ?>
```

(more info: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_post_thumbnail)

Now add the image to your post or page under 'set featured image', and skip using custom fields and post_get_meta.

Comment: I wish it was, but its not.  I have simplified the process for the purposes of this post but the eventual code does a lot more than just resize the image.  I left it out as it is not releveant to the issue at hand.

Comment: ok gottcha...  seems like we need to see more of your actual code here.  Also: "this issue only seems to happen with a couple of posts" - have you tried a fresh wordpress install and new test posts?

Comment: I think im going to end up going down that route, its really strange, certain posts create certain extra images.  I can't get to the bottom of it.  The update 3 code I posted above shows it requesting two separate posts from the DB but i cant see why

Comment: Sounds like it would be useful for WordPress to provide post-upload image processing hooks.

Comment: Can you run your imagemagick script on the admin page instead of on the public facing page?  So that the processing happens when the admin saves the post, not when the public views that page?  That seems like it would increase performance and solve some other potential issues other than the one you're running into above.  Check out [**section 5 - show meta box** of Noel Tock's excellent custom post type tutorial.](http://www.noeltock.com/web-design/wordpress/custom-post-types-events-pt1/)